# Laravel 8 api $request is really strange

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I am sending This request form vue component:

```
 data(){
    return{
        email:"s@me.com"
    }
},
methods:{
    reset(){
console.log(this.email)
return axios.post(API_URL + '/auth/resetpass', this.email)
    .then(() => {
      this.$router.replace({
        name: "login",
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("failed:" + error);
    });
    }
}
```

Console log comes as s@me.com

In controller $request->email is null

If I do

```
public function reset(Request $request)
{
$email = $request-all();
return response()->json(['email' => $email]);
}
```

This is when I get this

```
{"email":{"s@me_com":null}}
```

What is this?? Please help. What am I not seeing?

Comment: What does `dd($request->input())` return? It looks like however your data is being sent is mapping your Email Address as the `key`, with a `null` value. That explains why `$request->email` is null, it would be `$request->{"s@me_com"}`, which is obviously something you can't hard-code and account for. I think you'll need to debug and adjust your front-end code to send the correct info; it's backwards (somehow)

Answer (score 2):

Give the name `email` to the input since you're using `$request->email`.

```
axios.post(API_URL + '/auth/resetpass', {email: this.email})
```

what you are using right now is equivalent to

```
axios.post(API_URL + '/auth/resetpass', this.email)
//==
axios.post(API_URL + '/auth/resetpass', {this.email: ''})
//no value became null form a laravel middleware
```